# Rename field in projection when using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, projection

I would like to rename a field in a projection but this does not work when using Kotlin and the MongoDB Java driver. Can this be done with the Java driver?

```kotlin
    collection
        .find()
        // field removal works
        .projection(
            fields(exclude("excludefield1","excludefield2"))
        )
        // field rename does not work
        .projection(new Document("newfieldname","$oldfieldname"))
        .forEach...
```

Comment: Can you write aggregations in kotlin?

Comment: I think the fact that the code is Kotlin is not relevant so i have rewritten the example in Java.  Do I need the `aggregate` to rename a field?

Comment: Yess, you can do this easily in `$project` stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "newField": "$oldfieldname",
      _id: 0 // Optional
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ns0dZe5lZk4)

Edit:

If you have more field than fields you want to exclude, you should use `$project` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "newField": "$oldfieldname",
      "includeField": 1 //Fields other than this will be excluded
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6NSdGCn88--)

Answer (score 0):

When using the Aggregation Framework, this can also be done as follows

1. Use Projections.computed

`project(fields(computed("newname", "$oldname")))`

2. Use Aggregates.addFields

`addFields(Field("newname", "$oldname"))`